# If a US citizen shows up at the US border with no US passport, are immigration officials obligated to help them prove their identity?

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration

(Note: this is US-specific but if other countries have similar laws it would be interesting to hear the analogous situations as well)

I know that the law states that US citizens have the right to enter the US *based on their status as a citizen alone*, not on on their possession of a passport; that is, it is illegal to deny entry to a US citizen simply because they don't have their passport.

So for example, if an American shows up to a US border without their passport but with a driver's license or some other form of ID, it might be a more laborious process, but they will be let in once their identity can be proved.

However, what if hypothetically, someone who claims to be a US citizen shows up with nothing at all?  Are immigration officials obligated to do everything they possibly can (e.g. going to that person's house to get their ID, summoning their acquaintances for interview; I'm honestly not sure what else ...) to help the person prove their identity, or in that case are they allowed to turn them away?

Comment: They might have to help a US citizen... But how would they know it's a US citizen?

Comment: Government databases, fingerprint scans and matches, retrieval of official photographs, etc.

Comment: [Here](https://www.shusterman.com/pdf/cbpinspectorsfieldmanual.pdf) is a copy of the CBP Inspectors Field Manual, circa 2008.  Chapter 12 has guidance on evidence of citizenship.  It's not very detailed, but that may be all the instructions that border agents get.  But there certainly isn't any mention of a requirement to go to great lengths to help someone prove their citizenship.

Comment: If there was a requirement to assist, that would be a great way to tie up US government resources and funds - keep going back to the border and demanding assistance to prove citizenship.  Have a thousand people a day do that.  Would be a great way to protest.  But I doubt such a requirement exists, given that the police have no duty of care to you, why would immigration officers?  By turning away someone claiming to be a citizen, they aren't turning away a US citizen, they are turning away someone claiming to be one - I doubt that would violate US law.

Comment: Note that except at the land borders where you can easily “bounce“ someone, you would generally need to ascertain a person's identity and citizenship to make sure they would be admitted in the place they came from or to identify another place where you could send them to. I am less familiar with the US but at airports in Europe, it's not uncommon for people to ditch their passport and for the police to involve foreign consulates to obtain a *laissez-passer*.

Comment: The authorities also generally prefer to identify the person in case they are being sought for other reasons and to record the refusal to let them enter. In other words, it's not an either/or situation. Police is likely to make an effort (within reason) to determine the person's identity, not only out of an obligation to assist citizens but for their own purpose, even if they don't believe you and want to turn you away.

Comment: @NateEldredge It seems the entire Chapter 17 on Inadmissible Aliens is missing. It seems that if someone claims they are a US citizen and a CBP agent is not satisfied that this is the case, they would have to follow the procedure in section 17.4 (and probably 17.8 or 17.15). I have no idea what this entails but agents could be required to investigate further, not specifically to “help” the person but to fulfill other legal requirements and procedures.

Comment: An analogous situation, regarding the European Union:

“Where a Union citizen, or a family member who is not a national of a Member State, does not have the necessary travel documents or, if required, the necessary visas, the Member State concerned shall, before turning them back, give such persons every reasonable opportunity to obtain the necessary documents or have them brought to them within a reasonable period of time or to corroborate or prove by other means that they are covered by the right of free movement and residence.” Directive 2004/38/EC, article 5(5).

Comment: I suspect this happens quite often actually. People might go to Tijuana for a good time, get drunk, and lose their wallet. I would wager a few dollars there's already a well established protocol for this scenario. In very questionable cases my (admittedly ignorant) guess would be that they would refer the person to the nearest Embassy or Consulate.

Comment: I came back one time with an expired passport and they just looked me up on the computer after giving me the wtf face. I saw they had 2 pages of text on me, but couldn't read any of it. The whole thing was handled very quickly and that was post 9/11

Comment: @Relaxed: a partial copy of  missing chapter 17 can be found [here](https://foiarr.cbp.gov/docs/Manuals_and_Instructions/2012/158430202_910/1202071451_IFM_RH_redacted_582(2)_reading_room_Part5.pdf). It is lightly redacted, and some of last few sections are missing, but it contains the important section 17.4 about suspected false claims of US citizenship, and how to handle them.

Answer (score 62):

They're not legally obliged to help, but if the person claims US citizenship and the immigration officer is not convinced, the immigration officer does not have discretion to refuse entry: the person claiming US citizenship must be brought before an immigration judge, who must decide whether the person is a US citizen.

Comment: Which might mean waiting two years in custody for the court date. Better don't try it.

Comment: @Aganju whether or not it makes sense to try it depends rather on the strength of one's evidence and the relative difficulty of this route compared to getting a passport at the nearest consulate.  In practice it's hard to imagine being able to convince a judge more readily than an immigration officer unless the officer is being particularly difficult.

Comment: If you're going before a judge, then at some point you might have access to a lawyer, or at least a phone call.  At that point, your best bet is to call friend / family, and have them bring ID items to your location as best they can.

Comment: Sometimes witnesses and maybe forensic evidence is the only possibility. For example, a US citizen goes to a holiday, is robbed, losing all documents. At the same time, his house at home is struck by lightning, burns down, destroying all other documents or copies of documents he had. It's unlikely but among millions of people it should be almost sure it happened before.

Comment: @DJClayworth Citation for what? No citation needed. It’s just true. You can google it and find cases. It’s happened at the Mexico border a few times including one I read about myself.

Comment: @DJClayworth, how is this "massive abuse" going to pan out? Sure, I can show up every day for a year, say "I claim my right to enter as a US citizen", and be told "Please wait over there for a few minutes." Then an hour and a half later, they come out and tell me my case is still under review by the judge I saw three months ago. So what's the point? And what damage have I inflicted?

Comment: @phoog Can you give a citation for someone being able to show up at the border, claim to be a US citizen with absolutely no evidence to back it up (and an implausible claim) and not be turned away? What happens between them showing up and coming before a judge? Are they made to wait at the airport?

Comment: @DJClayworth most likely they'd be in immigration detention, and as Aganju suggests, it's certainly possible that this could go spectacularly badly and take months or years: there have been similar cases in the press.  I don't have time to find the citation just now but I will do so in the next day or so and add it to the answer.

Comment: @Stewart because this would not be a criminal case, however, the government would not pay for the lawyer, and someone arriving at the border with "nothing" would be hard pressed to pay, making things even more difficult.  But outside help, whether from a lawyer or family, would probably be essential in such a case.  There have been cases in the news of US citizens born in Mexico or the Caribbean being deported to their country of birth because of inadequate documentary evidence of their citizenship. Someone born in the US would be in a better position.

Comment: @phoog Thanks, that's excellent. It might be worth adding to the answer that the applicant would be in immigration detention while awaiting a judge - that's relevant information for me, because I would rather be outside the country gathering information to prove my citizenship that in US immigration detention.

Comment: I'm curious, are there any land borders where the US immigration booth is on the foreign side of the border? If so, might the rules be different there? I imagine they would not let the person in if they claimed US citizenship without convincing evidence.

Comment: I suspect this might be one of the few cases where possessing ludicrously bad command of any foreign languages will help.

Comment: @Joshua while that's a jest, it's not without merit. In Europe during the 90s, immigration officers used language skills of refugees as a quick judgement - many claimed to be from country X, knowing only that there's a war there and therefore they'd be accepted as refugees, but not knowing that the language there is A, while their own language is B. I had an acquaintance working in the field and her boss spoke fluent A. Entering the room with a quick welcoming phrase and question in A and looking into a puzzled face was all it took him to debunk their story.

Comment: @Joshua a person's lack of skills in a certain language can clearly not be tested, since anyone that is fluent in a language can fake not knowing it by simply not using it...

Comment: @a20 I disagree. It's trivial for an experienced investigator to deploy a tiny bit of theatre to catch someone who's faking. For example, enter the detention room quickly with wide-open eyes, leave the door open, and in pressured speech in the certain language say "There's a fire, we need to get you out of here." The emotional content will override the subject's desire to appear to not understand.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica I'm not convinced. To test it, you would need to induce a certain emotional state in the subject, but, for this to be effective, the person speaking must also say it in a certain way. Just quietly walking into the room and monotonously stating that there's a fire will not have an effect, instead one will have to really show an upset state, and this is understandable in any language. The subject could thus once questioned simply say that "He barged in here all shouting and waving and I think I heard the word "fire", so I reacted and got worried"

Comment: @Aganju per EOIR practice manual, claim status reviews are supposed to be heard within 7 days, preferably 24 hours, though these aren't binding and the case can be continued to allow either side to develop additional evidence.

Comment: @Joshua The land border infrastructure is always on the US border, but there are Preclearance stations for air and train entry, and they likely would not have to do this.

Comment: @aidanh010 Yes, I think that at a preclearance location, they are not obligated to allow a person to board if they cannot prove their US citizenship, since US citizens are (in most cases) legally required to use a US passport to enter the country. But I am not sure about this.

Comment: @Brian Exactly, at preclearance US citizens strictly need a passport or (for preclearance at Canadian airports) NEXUS card